# Magento 1.7 checkout steps don't open

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

I added products to my cart, when i proceed to checkout, none of the steps open when i click on them, even if i begin by clicking on billing information.

how to un-stuck them ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using an extension for the checkout to bypass the login step. By default should have 6 steps. If you really don't know the module that could be the culprit you can add template path hints and block name path hints to your output. It may give some clues. You can also check your console for JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to bypass the login/guest checkout step?
It would seem that something is failing at this stage.

Comment: how can find out about that ? How do i know which method i am using ? is it in the admin ?

Comment: If you haven't done this yourself, is this checkout an extension?

Comment: no, i'm not using extensions for the checkout.